# gallery with flip action for individual items in android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am trying to Build a gallery in Android ( Not exactly what is already existing in android , by gallery I mean a set of images being displayed together ).

I want to build something like this :
http://www.simpleviewer.net/tiltviewer/app/
(Ignore the 3d affect.. )

A set of images that can be flipped to see the text behind.
The list of images is dynamic and also the content .( I would be getting the list from web )
Also two images could have been flipped on one side and two can be on the other side.

I initially referred 3dTransition : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transition3d.html and understood a little about transitions.

Do I have to create 10's of ImageViews according to list and place it dynamically or do I have a better approach.

Referred  : [Android + Use ViewFlipper to flip individual items within a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947267/android-use-viewflipper-to-flip-individual-items-within-a-listview)
But the list view can show one item in a row.. I want to show two to three items. Also individual Items must be clickable and not the complete row.
referred http://code.google.com/p/shelves/ , to implement multiple items in a list row. So is that the way to go ?

How do I display text ? Inflate layout as many as Imageview ?
Or one layout file would do ? (How ? ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally implemented it in this way :

A GridView as top layout.

Each child layout having a `ViewFlipper` with two views . one for image and other for text.
I attached an `onlClick` event on griditem `onChildItemClick`

Note : the swype (fling) action wouldn't work in this screen due to problems of detecting a fling gesture in a scrollable view. This might help : http://www.jmstudio.org/archives/391 or can look here too [Swipe/Fling tab-changing in conjunction with ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102993/swipe-fling-tab-changing-in-conjunction-with-scrollview)