# Android Expandable ListView Child Click

Tags: android

I am using a view flipper.Expandable list view is also a child of that viewflipper.I want to open another child of viewflipper when i click on child of expandable list.And i also want to send data of expandable list's child on click event.

Comment: you can receive the click event(click on child element)  by setting the onchildClickListener. Override onchildClick() and perform the stuff their

Answer (score 0):

Use the below link.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947267/android-use-viewflipper-to-flip-individual-items-within-a-listview
```

It have an example of  ViewFlipper to flip individual items within a ListView