# How to flip an item in a ListView using ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, viewflipper, onitemclicklistener

I've used a viewflipper xml as row xml for viewlist , but when I touch on  any viewitemlist just the top item on screen flips! I know it's because they have same ID (it's like having multiple ViewFlipper with same id on a layout).

I've used `SimpleCursorAdapter()` to create my listview (in Activity not ListActivity).

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.viewFlipper:
            vf.showNext();
            break;
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

I've tried `OnItemClickListener()` too (same result).

Comment: Could you show us the line where you create and set up the `SimpleCursorAdapter()`. Thanks.

Comment: `adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, FROM, TO, 0);`

Comment: Hey NewDev, now I find `SimpleCursorAdapter()` quite annoying because it takes a lot of control away from developers. The cost for "easyness" is difficulty adding functionality down the line. If you do wish to use this, have a read of `ViewBinder` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html . You should then set the click listener on the view each time afterwards. This way you don't have to use `findViewById` inside the click listener.

Comment: Thanks. I've used `ViewBinder` for changing and modifying data but how to use it for `onClickListener`?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link answer to get information about list view with view flipper implementation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44106602/651377